# Xamarin forms: Bind byte array to ImageCell ImageSource in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I can't find a clear answer on how to bind a byte array to the ImageSource of an ImageCell in an ListView.

```
    <ListView x:Name="listEntries" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ImageCell
            Text="{Binding Barcode}"
            ImageSource="{Binding Image}"
            >
          </ImageCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I realy have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: The `Image`-Property is a byte-array? If yes, than use a converter to convert the byte[] to an ImageSource

Comment: Why do you even try to bind a `byte[]` as an image? Make that array an image before binding

Comment: @Tomtom No, the 'Image'-Property is a string (got it from an example, but the string was een URL to an image online). So I have no idea with what I have to fill Image.

Comment: @lokusking You can't bind an image to an imageSource.. or can you?

Comment: If the source of the image is an Uri, you can use the [`ImageSource.FromUri`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromUri/p/System.Uri/) method to create an ImageSource form that Uri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oke, I found the **solution**.. 
I took it way to far, because of the examples/same problems I found online.

I changed the 'Image'-Property from `String` to `ImageSource` and then filled it with `'ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(pictureByteArray))'`

And it worked!